# MailChimp and Wordpress Integration for E-Book download

Tags: wordpress, automation, integration, mailchimp

I'm a little new to web dev and coding so forgive my basic question..

I'm working as a sales and marketing consultant for a software company. The company has requested i create a mailchimp campaign linking to a landing page on wordpress, with downloadable e-book for subscribers. I'm having difficulty with this; does anyone have a recommendation or solution to integrate/automate the two?

To be more concise, there's three actions required: Sending the campaign (Mailchimp), redirecting to the landing page (Wordpress), and then downloading E-Book AFTER subscribing (Wordpress). All these actions have been completed; I just don't know how to automate/integrate the actions together.

i realize it's not a coding question per se, but I assume some coding may be needed.

Thanks :)

P.s. I searched for a similar question but to no avail. If there is one, please link the answers :)

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the mail chimp plug-in? 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/
-Good luck [:

Answer (score 0):

I have had to create a similar workflow, below is my process.

1. Create a **list** on mailchimp

   - within this list, in the forms tab, create a form to get name and email info of people wanting to download your Ebook
   - open '**embedded forms**' in the same list and copy the HTML code
2. Using the **Bloom** plugin connect mailchimp and wordpress.

   - selected the mailchimp list you want to connect
   - select '**custom HTML form**' and paste the code
   - make final aesthetic changes to from
   - Bloom will give you a 'shortcode for the optin' which can be copied into a black wordpress page. (this will show your form)
3. Create a landing page on wordpress

   - standard page nothing special but link to you wordpress page with your form
4. Set up **automation** on Mailchimp that whenever someone signs up to your list they get an email with a link to the Ebook.

That's the overview, with many learning opportunities along the way ;)